# Missing grant type error, When generating new Token from Refresh Token using Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to generate new token from refresh token.

I am making rest call using spring Rest Template as below.

```
    String clientCredentials = "Client Id value here + ":" + " Client Secret value here";
    String encodedCredentials = new 
    String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(clientCredentials.getBytes()));    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
    HttpEntity<String> req = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    Map<String, Object> parametersMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    parametersMap.put("grant_type",  "refresh_token");
    parametersMap.put("REFRESH_TOKEN", "<refreshToken Value here>");
    
    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(accessTokenUrl)
                    .queryParam("client_id", "<Client Id value>")
                    .queryParam("client_secret", "<Client Secret value>")
                    .build();
                    
    ResponseEntity<OAuthToken> resp = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, req, OAuthToken.class, parametersMap);
```

I am getting below Exception

`2021-01-28 09:27:35,474 WARN  [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint] (default task-29) () Handling error: InvalidRequestException, Missing grant type
2021-01-28 09:27:35,475 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (default task-29) () SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-01-28 09:27:35,476 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-29) UT005023: Exception handling request to /oauthApp/oauth/token: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is error="invalid_request", error_description="Missing grant type"
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)`

At Server side in class that extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter, I have below code.

```
 @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("client_id")
        .secret("client_secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials","implicit");
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailService);
    }
```

Comment: Note that your parameter name is incorrect; it should be `refresh_token` (lowercase).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-
Thanks it worked.

Another I want to check is can retrieve "Refresh token" from token once it is expired?

I am using below code to retrieve refresh token. 
When token is not expired it working. But when token is expired its not working

Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(TOKEN_SECRET.getBytes("UTF-8"))
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();